# How to covert output into list and store it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is the code

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

ps = PorterStemmer()

for w in Wrd_Freq:
   print(ps.stem(w))
```

Output

```
read
peopl
say
work
```

I need the output as

```
['read',
 'people',
 'say',
 'work']
```

Full Code without Potter Stemmer

```
lower = []
for item in df_text['job_description']:
lower.append(item.lower())           # lowercase description

tokens = []
type(tokens)

token_string= [str(i) for i in lower]                                                 
string = "".join(token_string)  
string = string.replace("-","")
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r"\W+", gaps=True)
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(string)

tokens

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english')
tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in stopwords_list]
tokens
freq6000 = []
Wrd_Freq = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
Wrd_Freq

df_WrdFreq = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Wrd_Freq, orient='Index') 
df_WrdFreq.columns=['Word Frequency']     


freq6000= df_WrdFreq[(df_WrdFreq['Word Frequency'] >= 6000)] 

freq6000.sort_values(by=['Word Frequency'],ascending=False).head(10)
```

I need to use potter stemmer separately to check whether there is any change to the count list. I need to perform the same after including potter stemmer and compare the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
L= [ps.stem(w) for w in Wrd_Freq]
```

EDIT:

If need top values by counts:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english')
tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in stopwords_list]
tokens
freq6000 = []
Wrd_Freq = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)


from collections import Counter

c = Counter(tokens)
top = [x for x, y in c.most_common(10)]
print (top)
['data', 'experience', 'business', 'work', 'science',
'learning', 'analytics', 'team', 'analysis', 'machine']


df_WrdFreq = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Wrd_Freq, orient='Index') 
df_WrdFreq.columns=['Word Frequency']     


freq6000= df_WrdFreq[(df_WrdFreq['Word Frequency'] >= 6000)]
```

---

```
df = freq6000.sort_values(by=['Word Frequency'],ascending=False).head(10)
print (df)
            Word Frequency
data                124289
experience           59135
business             33528
work                 28146
science              26864
learning             26850
analytics            21828
team                 20825
analysis             20607
machine              20484
```

Comment: Thanks it worked . One more question how can i count the frequency of each words  from the list and then filter out the top 10?

Comment: @Zac - So new list are all values without top10? Or top10 values?

Comment: The list i got has all the values and  its not sorted . I need to filter out top 10 words.

Comment: the count i got without using Potter Stemmer  is shown below    
Word Frequency
data
124289
experience
59135
business
33528
work
28146
science
26864
learning
26850
analytics
21828
team
20825
analysis
20607
machine
20484                       But when i use potter stemmer  it give totally different result i dont know why?  I think something wrong with my counting ..

Comment: @Zac - Is possible see complete code? Also some data sample, 2-3 rows?

Comment: And what code return output from coment `the count i got without using Potter Stemmer is shown below... ` ?

Comment: i have posted the code and the dataset is a csv file and i am just analysing the text in one of the column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212160/discussion-between-zac-and-jezrael).